# Opening SharePoint 2010 Foundation Site in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hello I am trying to open a SharePoint 2010 Foundation Site (local installed on Windows7 Home Premium) in SharePoint Designer 2010. Nevertheless I get the following error:

"The directory name is invalid".

I already added the site to trusted zone in IE, but that has no effect. I also can't connect SharePoint to SharePoint Workspace.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you actually browse to the SharePoint site in a web browser?

Comment: Yes that is possible. Both the central administration and Defealt web application (:80) are accessible.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to SharePoint using "localhost" or your computer name?

Comment: I am using http://<computername>

Comment: After searching for some answers I tried to open the site in SharePoint Designer 2007. I got some more feedback: "This web site has been configured to disallow editing with SharePoint Designer. Contact your web site administrator for more information." After some research I came across this statement: For allowing site to be edited remove DisableWebDesignFeatures=wdfopensite from onet.xml But I dont know what file I have to adjust. There are many onet.xml files.

Answer (score -1):

First, are you using SharePoint Designer 2007 or 2010? You can't use SPD 2007 with SharePoint 2010.

Second, you have to configure your site (via central admin) to allow editing with SPD.

Comment: I am trying to open a SharePoint 2010 Foundation Site (local installed on Windows7 Home Premium) in SharePoint Designer 2010. I have enabled the following: http://bastiaanjacobs.nl/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Enable-SharePoint-Designer.png